# Does night mode on iPhone really help?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, health, light

Okay so I know that night mode is supposed to filter out blue light that is bad for the eyes, but is it really more helpful than annoying? At night I do use it when I’m on the phone but it doesn’t make sense to keep it on during the day when it’s bright outside does it?

Comment: Helpful for what?

Comment: To protect your eyes from high energy light waves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different colors mean different wave lenght and energy, as displayed in the picture. [image: Wave lenght]

Using Planck's theory, the shorter the wave is, the more energy it carries.
On day light, all these wave lenghts are present, including UV from sun. With no sun-light, your eyes aren't hit by those, so there's no need of using higher energy waves (that's exactly how night mode on iPhone works, using only lower energy waves).